# $L^1$ convergence and pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\} \subset L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ and $f, g \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ s.t.
\begin{align}
f_n \rightarrow f \qquad &\text{in } L^1 \\
f_n \rightarrow g \qquad &\text{a.e.}
\end{align}
Then should we have $f=g$ a.e.?

Comment: Hint: There is a subsequence $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because from $||f_n-f||_1\to 0$ we get a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging almost everywhere to $f$ and since $f_{n_k}$ converges almost everywhere to $g$ we must have $f=g$ a.e.

Comment: Why does this subsequence necessarily converge to $f$? I know that there exists a subsequence that converges almost everywhere to some $L^1$ function $g$. How to prove that this $g$ is in fact $f$?... Thank you